# AddEventListener with wrapper listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying run custom code whenever a click event is triggered. This is what I have so far:

```
const origHandler = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (eventName, eventHandler, options) {
    let handler = eventHandler;
    const target = this;
    origHandler.call(this, eventName, function (e) {
        // Do something with e
        doSomething(e);
        // Run original function
        handler.call(target, e);
    }, options);
};
```

I am also using [this multi-select dropdown plugin](https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select). With the code above, clicking on the dropdown element doesn't do anything until I click it a couple of times.
It works fine if I just do the following:

```
    origHandler.call(this, eventName, handler, options);
```

However, the above doesn't allow me to run custom code whenever the handler is called. Is there anything I can do to create a wrapper that also works with these types of plugins?

This problem is not specific to this plugin, as I have seen a few other plugins in the application also breaking as a result of this code.

Answer (score 2):

**Incomplete Algorithm**

The posted code calls (the original) `addEventListener` with an anonymous function argument. This means any `removeEventListener` in calling code which supplies `handler` as its function argument will fail - it never matches the anonymous function.

To successfully add a hook into `addEventListener` would require implementing a complementary hook into `removeEventListener` and additional logic to achieve correct removal of added listeners.

This doesn't mean the particular problems encountered are specifically caused by only patching `addEventListener`, but doing so is guaranteed to produce code failure.

In general patching `prototype` object properties of global functions is probably best avoided if at all possible.

**Alternative using Capture**

Adding a document click event listener that uses event capture, before including any library scripts, should allow inspection of every click event before being handled by anything else:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
       // do something with event
         console.log("click event type: %s on %s", e.type, e.target.tagName);
    }, {capture:true});
```

```css
body {background-color: white}
html {background-color: grey}
```

```html
Click me!
```